# Mozilla - Multiple mouse click when using jquery validation plugins submitHandler

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate, mozilla

Please refer : [jqueryvalidation.org/validate](http://%20jqueryvalidation.org/validate)

I am making an ajax request when the user clicks a button.
This **works fine in Chrome** . But in Firefox , the calls are getting aggregated.
If the user click the button the call is made once , if the user clicks the button again then two calls are made.
Same way multiple calls are made for single button click. Please help to fix this Firefox issue.

The submit is called from jquery validation plugins submitHandler.

```
$("#MyForm").validate({
      submitHandler: function (form) {
          postSettings();
      }
});

    function postSettings() {

        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://10.20.1.20/PostData.cgi",
                success: function (successData) {

                },
                error: function (errorData) {
                }

            });
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: what does submitHandler refers to?

Comment: please check this http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/